# Using batch file, get 4 chars after a substring match within another string?

Tags: batch-file, properties, dos

I am trying to come up with a method of extracting 4 characters that occur after a substring match in a string.   The closest thing I could come up with is terribly inefficient looking and doesn't even work all that well.  Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

```
@echo off
cls
SET "_TMPVAR=Ports|http:8000|https:8443|"
SET _TMPVAR=%_TMPVAR:|=,%
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%m in ("%_TMPVAR%") do (
  SET "_TMPVAR1=%%n"
  SET "_TMPVAR2=%%o"
)
SET _HTTPS=0000
IF "%_TMPVAR1:~4,1%"=="s" (
  SET "_HTTPS=%_TMPVAR1:~-4%"
)
IF "%_TMPVAR2:~4,1%"=="s" (
  SET "_HTTPS=%_TMPVAR2:~-4%"
)
SET _
ECHO SSL Port is %_HTTPS%
pause
```

Comment: whay is it "terribly inefficient looking"? if it works for you it's OK. BAT programming would never look efficient, as it depends on your definition of "look".

Comment: Are you looking for another way of writing your batch file so that it has the same output? Or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to shorten the code and/or improve it.  I want it to make sense to others who read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve it is to eliminate the seemingly unnecessary comma replacement:

```
SET "_TMPVAR=Ports|http:8000|https:8443|"
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=|" %%m in ("%_TMPVAR%") do (
  SET "_TMPVAR1=%%n"
  SET "_TMPVAR2=%%o"
)
```

Further, you can take advantage of the delimiter list to split on `|` *and* `:` to break up your schemes and ports, allowing you to put the logic inside the `FOR` statement:

```
@echo off
cls
SET "_TMPVAR=Ports|http:8000|https:8443|"
SET _HTTPS=0000
FOR /F "tokens=2-7 delims=|:" %%a in ("%_TMPVAR%") do (
    IF %%a==https SET _HTTPS=%%b
    IF %%c==https SET _HTTPS=%%d
    IF %%e==https SET _HTTPS=%%f
)
SET _
ECHO SSL Port is %_HTTPS%
```

An advantage of using the delimiter behavior is that it allows for port numbers of any length.